# Collapse childview ExpandableListview - nhaarman ListviewAnimations

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

Im using nhaarman's ListviewAnimation library https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations  which works great.

Though I have difficulty tweaking one of his options, which is ExpandableListview. I want to tweak it so that only 1 child view (content view)is visible at a time. So when expanding a parent view (title view) item it should close the previous one. I can't seem to update (notify) my adapter when a child view is visible (is expanded). I have a custom adapter which extends ExpandableListItemAdapter.

This is the class [here](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/library/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/ExpandableListItemAdapter.java) .

Each item is set with the TitleViewOnClickListener, which handles the expanding ad collapsing of the content view.

Now I would like to collapse all visible child views and keep the selected open. Could anyone here help me or guide me in the right direction?

Next to that I can't seem to get an onlistitem click.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a `setLimit(int)` function to the `ExpandableListItemAdapter` class. When the `(limit+1)`th item is expanded, the first expanded item will collapse.

In your case, you could call `setLimit(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(final int groupPosition) {
   return 1;
}
```